# Image right over another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have two images overlapping each other, below is a vinyl and above is the spinning light effect. Also, I have an `onclick` event on the image below that when clicking it the vinyl starts spinning.

You can see what I'm talking about [here](http://vtxfactory.com), it's on the top left corner.

My problem is that the image right over don't let me trigger the `onclick` event, just in some short spaces as the spinning effect is a smaller image.

Is there any `html/css` command that can help me with this? Like making the spinning effect virtually invisible when hovering any part of the vinyl?

Comment: Which image you are talking about? groove1.png, groove2.png ?

Comment: It wass both of them but another coder gave me the answer, now I have just one image groovess.png overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a property in CSS 'pointer-events' which you have to set to 'none'.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: That's exaclty what I was looking for, just add the pointer-events: none; to the css styling, thank you!